# Deathstroke's Gear

Tags: dc, arrowverse, arrow

I need to ask about deathstroke's gear. I wanna know all about Deathstroke's gear specifically this thing:

[image]

I specifically wanna know are the things circled. i hope you guys can help. Thank You In Advance

Comment: Remember when DC embraced the cheese and they would call their heroes and villains by the full names they were given?  Possessor Zoom The Reverse Flash was my favorite but gosh I miss called Slade, Deathstroke the Terminator -huff-

Answer (score 11):

It looks like they're [grenades](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/40mm_grenade) for a [grenade launcher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grenade_launcher#Underslung) stored in a [bandolier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandolier).

Comment: Not sure why he's bothering to wear body armor if he's going to keep his grenades right there.

Comment: Depending on their designs they may not even be affected if struck by incoming fire. I also suspect if he thought he had to worry about them he would already have used them.

Answer (score 6):

They could be ammunition for a M79 Grenade launcher (as depicted in Terminator 2)

[image]

Or a M203 grenade launcher attachment (often attached to AR-15/AR-16 rifles)

[image]

For all I know those two weapons use the exact same ammunition, regardless, they are rounds for a grenade launcher.